# Variant class using generic programming

Tags: c++, c++11, variant-type

My goal is to learn a bit more about generic programming in C++. So, one of the trickiest things I've heard you can do is creating a Variant class. This took me a while and I needed to read and study a few implementations:

```
#ifndef VARIANT_HPP_INCLUDED
#define VARIANT_HPP_INCLUDED

#include <cstddef>
#include <typeindex>
#include <type_traits>

#include <iostream>

namespace spaceengine
{
    namespace utils
    {
        template<typename... Ts>
        struct VariantHelper;

        template<typename F, typename... Ts>
        struct VariantHelper<F, Ts...>
        {
            inline static void Destroy(const std::type_index typeIndex, void* data)
            {
                if(typeIndex == std::type_index(typeid(F)))
                    reinterpret_cast<F*>(data)->~F();
                else
                    VariantHelper<Ts...>::Destroy(typeIndex,data);
            }

            inline static void Move(const std::type_index oldTypeIndex, void* oldV, void* newV)
            {
                if(oldTypeIndex == std::type_index(typeid(F)))
                    new (newV) F(std::move(*reinterpret_cast<F*>(oldV)));
                else
                    VariantHelper<Ts...>::Move(oldTypeIndex,oldV,newV);
            }

            inline static void Copy(const std::type_index oldTypeIndex, const void* oldV, void* newV)
            {
                if(oldTypeIndex == std::type_index(typeid(F)))
                    new (newV) F(*reinterpret_cast<const F*>(oldV));
                else
                    VariantHelper<Ts...>::Copy(oldTypeIndex,oldV,newV);
            }
        };

        template<>
        struct VariantHelper<>
        {
            inline static void Destroy(const std::type_index typeIndex, void* data){}
            inline static void Move(const std::type_index oldTypeIndex, void* oldV, void* newV) {}
            inline static void Copy(const std::type_index oldTypeIndex, const void* oldV, void* newV) {}
        };

        template<typename... Ts>
        class Variant
        {
        public:
            Variant() : m_typeIndex(InvalidType()){}

            Variant(const Variant<Ts...>& old) : m_typeIndex(old.m_typeIndex)
            {
                HelperType::Copy(old.m_typeIndex, &old.m_data, &m_data);
            }

            Variant(Variant<Ts...>&& old) : m_typeIndex(old.m_typeIndex)
            {
                HelperType::Move(old.m_typeIndex, &old.m_data, &m_data);
            }

            Variant<Ts...>& operator=(Variant<Ts...> old)
            {
                m_typeIndex = old.m_typeIndex;
                Variant<Ts...> temp(*this);
                HelperType::Copy(old.m_typeIndex,&old.m_data,&m_data);
                HelperType::Copy(temp.m_typeIndex,&temp.m_data,&old.m_data);

                return *this;
            }

            template<typename T>
            bool Is() const
            {
                return (m_typeIndex == std::type_index(typeid(T)));
            }

            bool IsValid() const
            {
                return (m_typeIndex != std::type_index(typeid(InvalidType())));
            }

            std::type_index GetTypeIndex() const { return m_typeIndex; }

            template<typename T, typename... Args>
            void Set(Args&&... args)
            {
                HelperType::Destroy(m_typeIndex,&m_data);
                new (&m_data) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
                m_typeIndex = std::type_index(typeid(T));
            }

            template<typename T>
            const T& Get() const
            {
                if(m_typeIndex == std::type_index(typeid(T)))
                    return *reinterpret_cast<const T*>(&m_data);
                else
                    throw std::bad_cast();
            }

            template<typename T>
            T& Get()
            {
                if(m_typeIndex == std::type_index(typeid(T)))
                    return *reinterpret_cast<T*>(&m_data);
                else
                    throw std::bad_cast();
            }

            ~Variant()
            {
                HelperType::Destroy(m_typeIndex,&m_data);
            }

        private:

            using DataType = typename std::aligned_union<1,Ts...>::type;
            using HelperType = VariantHelper<Ts...>;

            static inline std::type_index InvalidType()
            {
                return std::type_index(typeid(void));
            }

            std::type_index m_typeIndex;
            DataType m_data;
        };
    }
}

#endif // VARIANT_HPP_INCLUDED
```

What I'm really looking for is:

1. Is there anything that's usually required by a `Variant` that this class doesn't provide?
2. Have I missed anything else that's obvious?
3. Does my use of placement new mean that my `Variant` class is stack allocated, or have I misunderstood what placement new does?

One of the things that irks me is that the `boost::variant` class is very large; and it seems like my much smaller code does 100% of what I need. But I can't decipher `boost::variant` well enough to figure out what it does that mine doesn't do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does my use of placement new mean that my Variant class is stack allocated, or have I misunderstood what placement new does?

It does mean that, and your implementation using the `std::union` to provide sufficient allocated space appears to be valid.

Almost at least, because your implementation of `Variant::Set()` is not checking types. So if a type is accidentally passed which wasn't covered within `Ts`, respectively requires more allocated space, it is going to corrupt the memory.

---

> But I can't decipher boost::variant well enough to figure out what it does that mine doesn't do.

For instance, the boost implementation gives an [never empty guarantee](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/variant/design.html#variant.design.never-empty) which your implementation does not. You are explicitly handling the case in which the Variant is in an invalid state.

---

In `Variant::Set()`, you are explicitly destroying old `m_data`, but you are not reverting `m_typeIndex` to a safe state prior to invoking the new constructor.  If the new constructor would throw, it would leave `m_typeIndex` on the old value which is plain wrong.

Consider adding an `Variant::Unset()` method which handles save destruction instead and is guaranteed to set `m_typeIndex` explicitly to the invalid type.

This also leads to invoking the destructor on invalid states.

---

That recursion in the template of `VariantHelper`. Not going to lie - that's rather difficult to trace. A comment would have been in place, explaining what you are going to do.

Comment: Thanks for your review. Some questions, regarding Set, is there a way to check types at compile time? I've been scratching my head trying to see a way to do it (it's simple to add check for VariantHelper to return true, else loop).
    
When you say it doesn't support primitive types, do you mean `int`, `bool` etc? Because it certainly does; I'm missing something here.
    
The VarientHelper just loops through itself until the first parameter in the parameter pack is the one desired.

Comment: About the built-in types, my fault. I wasn't aware that calling the destructor is explicitly allowed even for built-in types, as long as it is in the scope of a template.  As for the type checking, you can do something like this for minimum effort: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16924234/2879325 , recursing through the list, and finally wrapped in a `static_assert`.